# AngularJS Add class to <td> which is generate dynamic by ngRepeat from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem with my table, because I have no idea how do it...

I have table in html which is generate dynamic by Angular with data from database and now I needed add some styles to td element. Style which I need add, I have get from database (background-color in rgb), but I don't know how?

Below is code which is generate by Angular in view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp.</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th>Article name:</th>
            <th>Colors in article:</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">1</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">2</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">3</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">4</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">5</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">6</th>
            <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | filter : search track by $index">
            <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
            <td>obrazek</td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="11_14_1167"><p class="ng-binding">11_14_1167</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="C,M,Y,K,P286,P218"><p class="ng-binding">C,M,Y,K,P286,P218</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="C"><p class="ng-binding">C</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="C"><p class="ng-binding">C</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | filter : search track by $index">
            <td class="ng-binding">2</td>
            <td>obrazek</td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="11_14_1171"><p class="ng-binding">11_14_1171</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="C,M,Y,K,P286,P7465"><p class="ng-binding">C,M,Y,K,P286,P7465</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="Y"><p class="ng-binding">Y</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="Y"><p class="ng-binding">Y</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="Y"><p class="ng-binding">Y</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="Y"><p class="ng-binding">Y</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="Y"><p class="ng-binding">Y</p></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code which generate the table above:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lp.</th>
                <th>image</th>
                <th>Article name:</th>
                <th>Colors in article:</th>
                <th ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:number">{{$index+1}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | filter : search track by $index">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>obrazek</td>
                <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="{{ column }}"><p>{{ column }}</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

And now I need get values from database of classes which start from 5th column to the last and to each add background style in rgb.
I don't know where this whole procedure make... in the angular or php site. 
I will be very pleased if someone write me how should be step looks like... :)

EDIT 29.10.15:
Print screens of database tables:

1. Table where I get data to the table: [image]
2. Table where I have classes: [image]

And the example code of one row, how I want to look like in the end:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | filter : search track by $index">
            <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
            <td>obrazek</td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="11_14_1167"><p class="ng-binding">11_14_1167</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="C,M,Y,K,P447,P218"><p class="ng-binding">C,M,Y,K,P447,P218</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="P447" style="background-color: rgb(39,46,32)"><p class="ng-binding">P447</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="P447" style="background-color: rgb(39,46,32)"><p class="ng-binding">P447</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="K" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0)"><p class="ng-binding">K</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="K" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0)"><p class="ng-binding">K</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x" style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255)"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x" style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255)"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in pokayoke" class="x" style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255)"><p class="ng-binding">x</p></td>
</tr>
```

The class is not required, I only need add  the style inline.

Answer (score 0):

I am simplifying it assuming you have the color name saved in the DB, say you have a simple obj like this:

```
  $scope.items = [{
    "color":"red",
    "value":12
  },{
    "color":"green",
    "value":12
  },{
    "color":"blue",
    "value":12
  },{
    "color":"pink",
    "value":12
  }];
```

Then in the HTML you can add inline style like this,

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items" style="background:{{item.color}}"><td>{{item.value}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Laub1dOjT6K6MAvsPSN1?p=preview)

Comment: But I already have one ngRepeat loop in td element, can I have more then one in this same element? One loop for different scope?

Comment: can you share the structure of your DB and the final outcome you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited question and added structure of DB and simple example how I want to it look like.